# how to finds draw extents includes my point extent in openlayers3

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, openlayers

i draw a DragBox on openlayers map and when i use drawend event, i can see thats extent.
and i have some point on my map. my point is selected in EXTENT want to check whether with using openlayers3 api

```
draw = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
        /* dragbox interaction is active only if alt key is pressed */
        condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
        /* style the box */
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
            })
        })
    });
    /* add the DragBox interaction to the map */
    map.addInteraction(draw);

    draw.on('boxend', function (evt) {

       //if(evt.target.getGeometry().getExtent()**.isContains(MYPOINT.extent)**)


    });
```

Comment: Look at this question bro <http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115500/how-to-find-markers-in-selected-dragbox-openlayers-3>