# How to find markers in selected dragbox openlayers 3?

Tags: geoserver, polygon, extents, openlayers

Here is a part of code,

```
draw = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
            /* dragbox interaction is active only if alt key is pressed */
            condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
            /* style the box */
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
                })
            })
        });
        /* add the DragBox interaction to the map */
        map.addInteraction(draw);

        draw.on('boxend', function (evt) {}
```

I googled but didn't find how will I do. I created a dragbox and added to map , I have some markers on the map. How I learn that dragbox contains markers or not ?

Answer (score 10):

Okay, let's rock these features out of the `DragBox`!

There are three options I have found to extract those features from the extent of the `DragBox`.

Considerations and assumptions:

- I couldn't extract the layer types (raster or vector) from the `map.getLayers()` object, so let's assume that we stored the feature layers in individual global variables.
- The features are stored in a variable named `featureLayer`.
- I changed the `altKeyOnly` condition to `shiftKeyOnly` to increase compatibility (in Linux pressing down the Alt key moves the active window around by default).

First method:

The first method is the most basic one as you can see in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/L7xjb6yx/

1. Make a shortcut variable:

   ```
   var features = featureLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
   ```
2. Make an empty array for the matching points and loop through the features stored in the `featureLayer` variable:

   ```
   box.on('boxend', function() {
       var featuresinBox = [];
       for (var i=0;i<features.length;i++) {
   ```
3. Check with the `ol.extent.containsCoordinate()` function if the actual point fits into the extent of the `DragBox`. If it fits, add it to the `featuresinBox` array:

   ```
   if (ol.extent.containsCoordinate(box.getGeometry().extent, features[i].getGeometry().getCoordinates())) {
       featuresinBox.push(features[i]);
   }
   ```

Second method:

The first method is very basic, it has the least chance to fail. However there are some helper functions in OpenLayers 3 written for feature [sources](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.html). One of these functions is called `forEachFeature()`, which will loop through the features for you. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/fk1mqq25/1/

1. Empty array for matching features:

   ```
   box.on('boxend', function() {
       var featuresinBox = [];
   ```
2. Call the `forEachFeature()` function with an `opt_this` variable (in my case it's called `e`):

   ```
   featureLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(e) {
   ```
3. Check. If it fits, it sits:

   ```
   if (ol.extent.containsCoordinate(box.getGeometry().extent, e.getGeometry().getCoordinates())) {
       featuresinBox.push(e);
   }
   ```

Third method:

The third method is the simplest, however it is in an experimental state as stated in the [API doc](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html). It uses an `ol.source.Vector` function, too, called `forEachFeatureInExtent()`. Use at your own risk. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/b0d5mhyd/3/

1. Empty array:

   ```
   box.on('boxend', function () {
       var featuresinBox = [];
   ```
2. Call the `forEachFeatureInExtent()` function with the extent of the `DragBox` and push every feature which is in the extent in the empty array:

   ```
   featureLayer.getSource().forEachFeatureInExtent(box.getGeometry().extent, function (e) {
       featuresinBox.push(e);
   });
   ```

There is a fourth method which manually checks if the coordinate(s) of a feature
is in the `DragBox` extent or isn't, but it's more complicated than the first method, which is safe enough to use in most environments.

Final notes:

- The `featuresinBox` array contains the exact copy of the matching features. You can extract any information from them with the corresponding functions. I only used the `.length` attribute for the sake of simplicity in my fiddles.
- For the fourth method: the `ol.Extent` object contains only the two opposite corners of the extent (as in every GIS approach, the first one is the lower left corner).
- If you have more than one feature layer, then you have to loop through every one of them, to make them count in the "query".
- If you have one or two dimensional features (lines or polygons), then you have to check every coordinates to make sure that they are completely in the `DragBox` (for them `getGeometry().getCoordinates()` returns an array of coordinates). The only exception is the `forEachFeatureInExtent()` function, but as it is in an experimental state, you shouldn't expect a 100% result.
- Little extra for playing with feature selection: http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/b0d5mhyd/4/

Comment: Hey bro , thank you very much , your answer was awesome.

Comment: My vote is +1 I am looking same thing for OpenLayer V2.x My requirement is i have few marker on the Map. User will be able to draw Polygon on the map. When Polygon draw completed then I want to fetch all the marker which are inside the Polygon. How can i achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: In OpenLayers 2, only the BBOX selection is implemented. If you want to select with a polygon, you have to write your own algorithm for it. You can build on `OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon` and `OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial`. You can find examples how to use them on the official page. If you get stuck with it, post a new question, we will be happy to help.