# How to get coordinates of Drag Box using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, coordinates

I'm pretty new to From Openlayers and I have a problem. I can draw a rectangle using `DragBox` on my OpenLayers 3 map. How can I get its coordinates? I tried `getGeometry()` but it returns '`null`'. I think I just added the 'drawing dragbox feature' to my map and I am not creating an actual rectangle. I am going to use the area inside these coordinates later. Here is my code:

---

```
        boxControl =new ol.interaction.DragBox
        ({
            condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
            style: new ol.style.Style
            ({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: [0, 0, 255, 1]})
            })
        });
        map.addInteraction(boxControl);
```

OpenLayers 3 is pretty new and most of the resources on the web are for 2.x and I couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer. There is a Question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115500/how-to-find-markers-in-selected-dragbox-openlayers-3)

So I wrote:

```
boxControl.on('boxend', function () 
{
      var a= boxControl.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      $('#taOzet').text(a); 
});
```

and it's returned:

3524005.462580891,4941742.299355211,
3524005.462580891,4609088.352258123,
4069460.0964239086,4609088.352258123,
4069460.0964239086,4941742.299355211,
3524005.462580891,4941742.299355211

there are 5 points with x-y coordinates also 1st and 5th ones are same, so they make a polygon, in my case a rectangle!
Thanks again.

Comment: `ol.interaction.DragBox`'s `getGeometry` method always returns a rectangular polygon. But the rectangle won't be an extent (i.e. a rectangle that is parallel to the x and y axis) when the map view is rotated.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="form1" action="submit">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="bbox3">Upper Left</label>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[3]" id="bbox3" placeholder="latitude"/>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[0]" id="bbox0" placeholder="longitude"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 ">
        <label for="bbox1">Lower Right</label>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[1]" id="bbox1" placeholder="latitude"/>
            <input type="text" style="font-size: x-small;"
                class="form-control" name="bbox[2]" id="bbox2" placeholder="longitude"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
//Dragbox - select
draw = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyonly,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.stroke({
            color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
        })
    })
});

map.addInteraction(draw);
//Dragbox - get coordinates to fields
    draw.on('boxend', function() {
        var string = draw.getGeometry().getcoordinates();
        itest(string);
});

function itest(myString) {
    var thebox = myString.toString().split(",");
    var long1 = thebox[0];
    var lat1 = thebox[1];
    var long2 = thebox[4];
    var lat2 = thebox[5];
    document.getElementById("bbox0").value = long1;
    document.getElementById("bbox3").value = lat1;
    document.getElementById("bbox2").value = long2;
    document.getElementById("bbox1").value = lat2;
}
```